# Can you identify a set containing a zebra and spider minifig?

Tags: set-identification

I have 2 bags of unopened Lego bricks but I cannot determine what set they belong to...bag 2 344R6 and bag 4 344R6. They are probably from Lego Junior. I can tell there is a zebra character minifig and a spider character minifig.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! Can you post a photo of the bags?

Comment: I don't think the marking you quote identifies the set, but with pictures we are often able to help.

Comment: @Lindsay: It sounds like we have an answer you're happy with.  Could you click the check box by the answer to "accept" it?

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Batman baddie ZEEEeeeebra-Man,

[image]

and tough gurl TA-TAH-Taaaarantula !!!

From Set *[70907-1 Killer Croc Tail-Gator](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70907-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*.

[image]

Comment: You guys are the best! That is it! Thanks so much! I have a very happy 5 year old!

Comment: You're welcome Gurl!  Happy to help!